# Replace logo when export is embedded into another website using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on a charting application. Once the chart is exported and embedded somewhere else via iframe I want a different logo to appear. I am using [twig](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/) to create templates. Here is my code below

```
{# block('chart_footer_logo') #}

<div class="chart-footer">
    {% if not plain %}
    <div class="footer-right">
        <a class="logo" href="mywebsite" target="_blank">
            <img class = "internal" src="{{ ASSET_PATH }}logo.png" height="18" />
            <img class = "external" src="{{ ASSET_PATH }}logo-external.jpg" height="18" />
        </a>
    </div>
{% endif %}
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
(function() {
try {
    function endswith(str, ends){
      if (ends === '') return true;
      if (str == null || ends == null) return false;
      str = String(str); ends = String(ends);
      return str.length >= ends.length && str.slice(str.length - ends.length) === ends;
    }
    var referrer = document.referrer.split('/')[2];
    if (endswith(referrer, "mywebsite.com")) {
        $(".logo.external").hide();
    } else if (endswith(referrer, "externalwebsite.com")){
        $(".logo.internal").hide();
    }
} catch () {}
})();
```

I do not understand why this wont give any results and no errors in the console either.

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure that document.referrer.split('/')[2] is not empty. And also try to replace str.slice(str.length - ends.length) with String(str.slice(str.length - ends.length)).

Comment: how can I check document.referrer.split('/')[2] is empty.

Comment: Open developer console in your browser and write console.log(document.referrer.split('/')[2]); after var refferer = .....

Comment: add console.log(document.referrer.split('/')[2]); after var refferer = ..... and reload page

Comment: Try to hardcode some string with expected url and check your program again.